# CakePHP 2.2.1 what is DRY method to highlight current menu item?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to implement highlighting of current menu item on my website.
For now I only found a `View::set` method `$this->set('activeMenuButton', 'posts');` in current view.

But I have 9 menu items in my website layout. For example:

```
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Main page', array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index'), array('class' => 'button'));?></li> etc.
```

How I can automatize checking of is current active page == $this->set('activeMenuButton', 'posts')? Or I'm supposed to add check to every < li > in layout?
Like a

```
if $activeMenuButton == posts { echo = 'class="activebutton"' } else { echo class="button" }?
```

It looks terrible to me but I can't think of no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery. Pass the `$activeMenuButton` with json_encode() to a javascript function, then check all the buttons.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know JS. Can you please provide me an example?